# Object.keys() not working in class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, node-webkit

I have a class which reads a LokiJS database upon initialization and saves the database in an object, whereby a collection corresponds to a name. I want to have a separate array which holds just the names. I would normally do this with Object.keys(obj), but in my case that returns an empty array.
The code I so far have is:

```
class Barbot extends EventEmitter{
    constructor(HOST, PORT, ioUID, lcUID) {
        super();
        var self = this;

        // lokijs databases
        this.dbCocktails = new loki('./src/JavaScript/Cocktails.json');
        this.dbBottles = new loki('./src/JavaScript/Bottles.json');
        //parameters
        this.cocktails = {};
        this.cocktailNames = [];

        async.parallel({
            db1 : function(callback){
                self.dbCocktails.loadDatabase({}, function(){
                    callback(null);
                });
            },
            db2 : function(callback){
                self.dbBottles.loadDatabase({}, function(){
                    callback(null);
                });
            }
        }, function(err, results) {
            // initialize some objects
            self.bottles = self.dbBottles.getCollection('Flaschen');
            var cocktailArray = self.dbCocktails.listCollections();
            for (let i = 0; i < cocktailArray.length; i++) {
                self.cocktails[cocktailArray[i].name] = self.dbCocktails.getCollection(cocktailArray[i].name);
            }
            self.cocktailNames = Object.keys(self.cocktails); // somehow that doesn't work here!
        })
    }
```

This class is then imported from a normal JS-script which is run from a node-webkit app (is this maybe the problem? Does HTML have a problem with the class definition?). So that when I initialize this class and then log the `Barbot.cocktails` and `Barbot.cocktailNames`, the `cocktails` is what I would expect but the `cocktailNames` are empty. When I run the same code outside of a class, everything works as it should and the array of the names is filled with the names of my cocktails. Can someone help me figure out where my problem lies??

Edit: Here's the Code I use to initiate the class:

```
var Bb = require('./src/JavaScript/BarbotClass');
var HOST = 'localhost',
    PORT = 4223,
    ioUID = "wjY",
    lcUID = "vbn";
var Barbot = new Bb(HOST, PORT, ioUID, lcUID);
console.log(Barbot)    
console.log(Barbot.cocktailNames); // Array[0]
```

second Edit:
So when I log the Barbot object from this everything seems to be initialized just fine. But when I try to access parameters, they seem not to be the right ones. E.g. it looks like it would access the protoype of the parameters?? I included a picture of how the console output looks like.
 [image]

Comment: I don't see anywhere `var self = this;`

Comment: *'Does HTML have a problem with the class definition?"* HTML has nothing to do with JavaScript classes. Whether the *JavaScript engine* in the browser where you're doing this has a problem with it will depend on whether that engine has ES2015 (aka "ES6") features yet. Recent Chrome and Firefox and Edge do. Others may not.

Comment: Sorry I did't write it in the code above, but I do have a `var self = this;` in my code. As for the error I get, it's just an error when I try to use `self.cocktailNames` because it's just an empty array. No other errors are displayed in the browsers console either.

Comment: @ChristophPohl Loki uses events https://rawgit.com/techfort/LokiJS/master/jsdoc/lokijs.js.html#line839. Try listening for warning event.

Comment: You should add the code where you instantiate the class and how you use it.

Comment: @MariusDarila I tried that just not but it didn't emit any warnings. That also makes sense since the problem doesn't seem to lie in the databases as the variable with the collections in it is completely fine and looks like I want it to. I just can't access any keys of it. So even accessing `this.cocktails['cocktail_name']`, where cocktail_name is any cocktail in the database does not work. It returns an undefined.